# Как программно обратиться к стороннему боту от моего бота?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот, который принадлежит мне, мне нужно, чтобы он обратился к этому боту: https://telegram.me/stickers 
То есть мог писать ему сообщения и обрабатывать результаты, как это можно сделать или где про это почитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-видимому это не поддерживается:
[Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.